# What is the quickest way to break Kulve Taroth's horns on pursuit level 1?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

With the latest version of MHW the new monster [Kulve Taroth](https://monsterhunterworld.wiki.fextralife.com/Kulve+Taroth) has been released. It is a siege style quest which you (mostly) have to do several times to gain the reward.

I know that it is possible to break the horns quickly, for an early end to the quest. For example, in this video:

However, this is not that easy, I always had to do it 3-4 times for the rewards. So I have some questions:

1. What is the best setup of all group members to attempt to break her horns on pursuit level 1?
2. What weapon/armor choices do you recommend?
3. If you were able to do it solo, what setup did you use?

I am not looking for a full guide on how to beat Kulve Taroth, Only for strategies for targeting her horns quickly.

Comment: Monster hunter doesn't work in the way of "best setup". It's 100% opinion. I can wreck with a gunlance, but will consistently triple cart with twin blades. Other players could have the opposite experience. That's why my answer said "weapon" instead of a specific one and general skills instead of exact armor pieces. They are all viable for the right player. a specific "best" equipment build is 100% opinion based.

Comment: @Rapitor It's not 100% opinion. There are builds/weapons which are just way stronger than others (charge blade). Yes it can differ from monster to monster, but I am asking about 1 specific monster. Also the question doesn't care about skill with any weapon. Just assume that every weapon type has been mastered

Comment: I don't think you can just handwave away the most critical aspect of the series; people have fought end bosses *naked*, and come out on top.  To say that skill is irrelevant is to dismiss a core component of the entire game.

Answer (score 3):

Not going to happen solo, sorry! A level 1 quest clear requires 4 people and even then it's not simple. Since the quest doesn't scale down for a single hunter, it's simply not possible do beat it solo at level 1.

Answer (score 2):

Much like Danmaku said, this is probably not possible with how the hunt is designed, but a highly skilled hunter and with overpowered stats, it may be possible to at least reach the lava cavern phase.

For weapon, you are going to want a **fire weapon with part breaker 3 and affinity built.** Fire helps the armor go into the molten state much faster, making it easier to break.

The first phase of the hunt is very easy to advance, even solo. Just make sure you land every fallen boulder on taroth and she'll move to the cavern at level 1.

The cavern fight is where things get iffy. You need to do considerable damage and break enough parts in order to move to the lava cavern. **You can build for flight and use the jump mantle** to help with this and at least get the horn plating off. Keep using fire and part breaker.

If you can get to the lava cavern, good job. **go back to camp and switch your weapon to something harder hitting** (fire could still work, but there are better weapons). You *have* to rely on the environment if you have any hope of progressing to the final fight. If you don't land all three boulders and have her in an eruption. You will not move on. In order to move on to the final battle, you must knock off Taroth's armor entirely, by doing a very large amount of damage. Not possible for a single player, unless you have a broken build and hit every environmental hazard.

If, by some miracle you fit the broken build criteria and get Taroth to the final fight. You need 2 things: **a weapon with partbreaker, and skills for easier and more often mounting**. Knock her down and bomb her horns as often as you can and keep the damage going (anywhere, not just horn... to trigger knockdowns).

So, it's likely not possible to clear it at pursuit 1... even with this guide. This guide, though, will get you far enough that the next run will be pursuit 3 or 4, which is definitely soloable.

Comment: I think an important emphasis (in your and Danmaku's answer) is that Kulve Taroth's hitpoints do *not* scale down for a single hunter. She's always at max health and designed for a group of four.

Comment: I'm sure this answer is well-intentioned, but most of the advice is based on early misunderstandings of the fight.

Answer (score -2):

Me and some oriental person did it in 2 runs with just the 2 of us. Nobody else even in gathering hub. Only once though. Was just a lucky pairing i guess. Being humble ill give most credit to her. Can do it alone if there is a good amount of others in other groups, but that's not really solo. You should be able to solo but the time it would take isn't worth it at all. I use Charge blade. armor doesn't matter much but part breaker obviously helps. I usually go with kulve taroth armor but anything with decent fire defense you'll be fine. P.s. if kt is doing his lava floor thing. Just lay there. If you stay down you won't take damage until you get up( besides original hit). It's counterintuitive to do so but works like a charm if stuck in the middle. It's lay and wait or die. So just lay there until you player gets up themselves. Lucky drops to most of you. Lol